# Rescue block for each cucumber step

Tags: ruby, cucumber

How can I create a wrapper for all of the steps in cucumber, for example to execute all of the steps with rescue block
You can better each step or something like this

Comment: Could you elaborate a little? What is the rescue block trying to achieve? Generally if a line of code doesn't work, it's inadvisable to "skip it and carry on regardless" -- that's just going to cause much more confusing errors/behaviour.

Comment: Perhaps something like [this](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby/issues/1316#issuecomment-474828029) would be useful for your problem?

Comment: This sound like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284887) to me.

Comment: You should have unit tests or Cucumber steps that expect expect a method to raise an exception when given bad input, but you defeat the purpose of testing if you simply through away all exceptions.